# Good book on Shiva Purana in Kannada/English

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, book-recommendation

I am searching for a good book on **Shiva Purana in Kannada or English**  language. But till now most of the websites suggest "The Immortals of Meluha" trilogy. I would like to know is it worth reading "The Immortals of Meluha" to understand most of the Shiva Purana or is there any other good book available??

Comment: Do you want complete Shiva Purana or book which can provide essence of Shiva Purana?

Comment: Well both are fine.